# C# Do While Message Box is active

Tags: c#, wpf, user-input, messagebox

I am working on a project in C# that requires user input from a pop-up message box.

I am also trying to have my code perform a series of tasks while the message box is active.

My goal is to have the MessageBox describe the tasks being performed and ask the user to observe and verify that they are being carried out.
I want these tasks to continuously be performed until the user clicks on a response in the MessageBox.

To create my message box, I am using:

```
MessageBox.Show(string <message>, string <caption>, MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
```

And the basic structure of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
var userInput = MessageBox.Show("Are tasks A, B, C running?", "winCaption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
while (// <No response to MessageBox>)
{
    // Task A
    // Task B
    // Task C
    if (userInput == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        // PASS
        // exit while loop
    }
    else
    {
        // FAIL
        // exit while loop
    }
}
```

I have found that when the MessageBox.Show() occurs & the pop-up window appears, the code seems to hang at that line until the user response is detected.

Is it possible to make this work? If not, are there any alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: Google *modal dialog*

Comment: You need to use a `Form` for that to be possible. When a `Form` is opened, the rest of your code continues. With a `MessageBox` the thread will indeed wait/halt until you close it.

Comment: If you don't want to create a non-modal form from scratch, you could perhaps start the tasks asynchronously (or in a background thread) before calling `MessageBox.Show(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about calling MessageBox on separate `Thread`?

```
var action = new Action(() =>
{
      var userInput = MessageBox.Show("Are tasks A, B, C running?", "winCaption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
      if (userInput == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
           // PASS
      }
      else
      {
            // FAIL
      }
});
new Thread(new ThreadStart(action)).Start();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox.Show` creates a modal dialog, meaning that execution on the thread stops until it is closed.  You'll need to create a new `Form` that displays instead of using the built in `MessageBox`.

Once you've created the form, call it like this:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.Show(); //Note that this will NOT be modal
```

Keep in mind that `Form` *does* have a way to display it modally called `ShowDialog()`.  It can be a bit confusing, so I'll summarize here:

```
MessageBox.Show(); //Modal
Form.Show();       //Not Modal
Form.ShowDialog(); //Modal
```